# What do lazy and uselist do in flask-sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

```
comments = db.relationship('Comments',backref='user',lazy='dynamic')

work = db.relationship('Work',backref='user',uselist=False
```

My question is why I use lazy and uselist, if I have 3 tables ("comment and work")
It would be ideal if you could explain to me what I am doing in those two lines.
Please, and thank you!

Comment: What do parts of the documentation do you not understand?

Answer (score 0):

I assume db is a relational database and .relationship is a table of relationships.

If that is the case then "lazy" and "uselist" are unshared attributes between 'comments' and 'work'. That's how I understand it. If I was wrong in my assumptions please let me know and I will correct it!

Comment: you're right ... but what does lazy = dynamic and uselist = false do

Comment: Do you have the schema for the database? That's a very specific question.